# Does Google have On Premise Docker Containers for their OCR/Read API similar to MSAzure Cognitive Services

Tags: docker, containers, handwriting

Does google GCP provide on-premise docker containers for their OCR/Handwriting API/solution similar to the way MS Azure has provided access to their cognitive-services-read container. If so, is the google container GPU aware on the on premise hardware.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: No, there is no Docker image available for download that containts the model(s) Google use for their OCR service.